# How to Increase the weight for one predictor variable?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, weights

Just read this news: "Zuckerberg agreed to increase the weight that Facebook’s algorithm gave to NEQ scores to make sure authoritative news appeared more prominently." My question is: how can we increase the weight/importance of a predictor variable to influence the outcome when building a model? Or for this case, is actually NEQ scores a part of the target variable (in other words, the target variable is composed from multiple objectives)?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say Facebook uses a model which evaluates the importance as following

`importance = b_1 x age + b_2 x location + b_3 x NEQ`.

`b_3` represents the weight that NEQ is assigned. If `b_3` is manually increased then it also increase the contribution to the overall importance.